# Max and min of $5 \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{6} x\right)+10 \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{6}x\right) +11.2$ without graphing

Tags: trigonometry

> $$P(x)= 5 \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{6} x\right)+10 \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{6} x\right) +11.2$$
>   How would you mathematically find the the max and min points of $P(x)$ without graphing?

I know that individually if say $5 \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{6} x\right)+11.2$ is of $c(x)$ then max and min would be when $\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{6} x\right)= 1$ or $-1$ ( max = 16.2 min = 6.2)

thanks in advance

Comment: There is no $t$ on the RHS of the first line. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Is Calculus not allowed ? The answer is very straightforward with calculus but I don't know if I should put it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that $$ \cos\ t=\frac{5}{\sqrt{5^2+10^2}},\ \sin\ t = \frac{10}{\sqrt{5^2+10^2}} $$

Hene $$ P(t)=\sqrt{5^2+10^2} \{ \cos\ t\sin\ \frac{\pi x}{6} + \sin\ t\cos\ \frac{\pi x}{6} \} + 11.2 $$ $$=5\sqrt{5}  \sin\ (\frac{\pi x}{6} + t)  + 11.2 $$

That is max$ =5\sqrt{5} +11.2$ and min$=-5\sqrt{5}+11.2 $

Comment: Multiplying and dividing by the hypotenuse to covert the sum of two ratios to one ratio is an extremely elegant trick !